# Xamarin ZXing.Net.Mobile - ResultPoint

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing

I am currently using the package ZXing.Net.Mobile for Xamarin Forms.
When I use the scanner, it produces a **ZXing Result** which is a class that has an array of **ResultPoints**. Can someone help me understand these points?
They don't seem to make sense. They are way off according to where the scanner is in my grid.

Comment: https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/ResultPoint.html - I think the points are in relation to the image captured by the camera, not your on-screen UI

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but the points do not match the points on the screen or the image captured. Basically, if I'm trying to scan a barcode on the 'top of my screen', I get a ResultPoint with the Y coordinate that is really big (meaning it was at the bottom of my screen?) ?? I don't understand this.

Comment: Are the ResultPoints depending on the camera resolution?

Comment: ZX is open source - you can review the code yourself if you really need to understand it's behavior.  I've just been making an educated guess